# How can i enable slide show in android?

Tags: android, slideshow

I'm doing a sample gallery application in that application i have a set of 10 images, here I successfully added a Slide show (the 10 images displayed continuously in certain time interval). Here I initially showed the images in a GridView, once the user click any one of images, it will show up in an Image view, here I add this functionality, **if the user won't do anything (the selected image is show in Imageview) for 2 to 3 minutes means, here I enabled the Slideshow feature**. I don't know how to enable this, guidance much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You have to use ViewFlippers. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8908962/603744 . Simply do this. and use TimerTask to call showNext() at a particular interval.And set animations for flipper

Comment: @AndroSelva: Did you get my point? for example, User interact with GridView Activity, he won't do anything for 2 mins, now i need to show the slide show, similar to our System, if we won't do anything means the screen saver get running automatically. the same thing i need