# How can i move my activity like slider when i swipe the page in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-activity, android-gesture

I want to make a movement between my activity when I swipe the page. While I swipe the page, the pages have to come with my hand movement.

I have detected the swipe direction using `SimpleOnGestureListener` and changed the activity on intent. But i'm not getting exactly what I want. I need that effect.

Comment: You can use ViewFlippers..

Refer this..[http://stackoverflow.com/a/8908962/1542636][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8908962/1542636

Comment: Thanx ganesh..i think it'll work ..Now i'll try this now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`While I swipe the page, the pages have to come with my hand movement.`

That's a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), then you use [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) or [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) or [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) (depending on specific needs, read the doc) to provide the content of each "page".

Answer (score 0):

you can implement left to right slide animation like one described here.  [Android Left to Right slide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)

Comment: Thanx meghal..I already tried this .. Its just an transition from left to right when intent calls..But i not expecting this result,

Comment: Ohh, if you want to have your screen to move along with your touch, you can use viewpagers