# Flip images using viewflipper in android without buttons

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am using the following method of flipping images: [How to set dymanic images to ViewFlipper in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908862/how-to-set-dymanic-images-to-viewflipper-in-android)

I do not want to flip using buttons. When the user touches the images or swipes the image I want to flip to the next image. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ViewPager. See these links:

[Implementing Horizontal View Swiping Using ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/)

[Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager, Updated](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

[Android Viewpager as Image Slide Gallery (Swipe Gallery)](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/)

and this Library

[Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Comment: Thanks I used viewpager.. Much better and made my life a lot easier.. I just do not know why I was wasting my time with viewFlipper. To anyone who needs to slide multiple images save ur time and use View Pager.. !

Answer (score 0):

this might Help..... animator is a folder in res and the s_out_*** is an xml file with a translate

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {

```
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        lastX = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();

        if (lastX < currentX) {
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;

            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.animator.s_in_fleft);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.animator.s_out_right);
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }

        if (lastX > currentX) {
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                break;

            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.animator.s_in_fright);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.animator.s_out_left);
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
}
    return false;
```

}