# Facing difficulty in image sliding . Images are coming via url (json)

Tags: android, json, slider, android-volley

I have to make a slider of images while images are coming via json. 
I have used for View Flipper.
Previously it was coming as a list view but i want to images should appear as a slider in horizontal instead of list view.
When i have made some changes it is not coming as a sliding of images.

why it is not coming as a slider ? 
I am not getting anything . I am getting blank screen .Please help how can i get sliding of images via hitting json url .

MainActivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String url = "http://f6aa763b.ngrok.io/api/v1/restaurants/get_featured_restaurants";
    // Movies json url
    //private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    //private ListView listView;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    //private SliderLayout imageSlider;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        //imageSlider = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // handler to set duration and to upate animation
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void close() {    
            }

            @Override
            public void flush() {    
            }

            @Override
            public void publish(LogRecord record) {    
            }
        };

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AnimateandSlideShow();
            }
        };


        pDialog.show();
        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                //movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("org_image_url"));
                                //movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                //movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                //movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                                //movie.setAddress(obj.getString("address"));
                                //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
                                // Genre is json array
                                /*JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);    

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        setFlipperImage(movieList);
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();    
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }    
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }*/    

    private void setFlipperImage(List<Movie> movieList) {

        for(int i=0;i<movieList.size();i++){
            Log.i("Set Filpper Called", movieList.get(i).toString()+"");
            ImageView org_image_url = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            //com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
// image.setBackgroundResource(res);
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(movieList.get(i).toString())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.bc)
                    .error(R.drawable.bc)
                    .into(org_image_url);
            viewFlipper.addView(org_image_url);
        }
        viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    }
    // method to show slide show
    private void AnimateandSlideShow() {
        viewFlipper.showNext();
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ViewFlipper

        android:id="@+id/flipper"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_margin="6dp" >
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  />
</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

Customlist Adapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
NetworkImageView _ImageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
         _ImageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
_ImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        return convertView;
    }    
}
```

Logcat

```
08-02 16:12:36.100 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley-2/lib/x86
08-02 16:12:37.785 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley-2/lib/x86
08-02 16:12:37.884 4782-4863/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true                                                                       
                                                                          [ 08-02 16:12:37.893  4782: 4782 D/         ]
                                                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb4018fc0, tid 4782                                     
                                                                          [ 08-02 16:12:37.943  4782: 4863 D/         ]
                                                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae507570, tid 4863
08-02 16:12:37.945 4782-4863/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-02 16:12:39.306 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/MainActivity: [{"id":1980,"name":"Yuuka - The St. Regis Mumbai","description":"Super Sushi","restaurant_type":null,"restaurant_url":null,"restaurant_facebook_url":null,"restaurant_google_url":null,"restaurant_zomato_url":"https:\/\/www.zomato.com\/mumbai\/yuuka-the-st-regis-mumbai-lower-parel","average_ratings":"4.1","profile_image_file_name":"1980.jpg","profile_image_content_type":"image\/jpeg","cover_image_file_name":null,"cover_image_content_type":null,"establishment_type":"Fine Dining","cost":"8000","cuisine":"Japanese","timing":"7:30 PM to 12 Midnight","extras":null,"phone_numbers":[{"id":2869,"restaurant_id":1980,"number":"022 30151995","created_at":"2016-07-26T06:38:29.016-04:00","updated_at":"2016-07-26T06:38:29.016-04:00"}],"org_image_url":"http:\/\/comida-dev.s3.amazonaws.com\/res_pro_images\/1980.jpg","thumb_image_url":"http:\/\/comida-dev.s3.amazonaws.com\/res_pro_thumb_images\/1980.jpg","address":{"area":"The St. Regis, Lower Parel","full_address":"The St. Regis, 462, Senapati Bapat Marg, Lower Parel, Mumbai,The St. Regis, Lower Parel,mumbai,maharashtra,india,"},"menus":[],"restaurant_offers":[{"id":751,"text":"\"A free glass of domestic red\/white\/sparkling wine per person\"","offer_link":"https:\/\/www.eazydiner.com\/\/mumbai\/yuuka-the-st-regis-lower-parel-223235","resource":"eazydiner"}]},{"id":1174,"name":"EXO - The St. Regis Mumbai","description":"Where's The Party?","restaurant_type":null,"restaurant_url":null,"restaurant_facebook_url":null,"restaurant_google_url":null,"restaurant_zomato_url":"https:\/\/www.zomato.com\/mumbai\/exo-the-st-regis-mumbai-lower-parel","average_ratings":"4.1","profile_image_file_name":"1174.jpg","profile_image_content_type":"image\/jpeg","cover_image_file_name":null,"cover_image_content_type":null,"establishment_type":"Lounge","cost":"5000","cuisine":"Finger Food","timing":"7 PM to 3 AM (Wed-Sun), Mon & Tue Closed","extras":null,"phone_numbers":[{"id":1642,"restaurant_id":1174,"number":"022 61628422","created_at":"2016-07-26T06:38:19.743-04:00","updated_at":"2016-07-26T06:38:19.743-04:00"},{"id":1643,"restaurant_id":1174,"number":" 022 61628000","created_at":"2016-07-26T06:38:19.744-04:00","updated_at":"2016-07-26T06:38:19.744-04:00"}],"org_image_url":"http:\/\/comida-dev.s3.amazonaws.com\/res_pro_images\/1174.jpg","thumb_image_url":"http:\/\/comida-dev.s3.amazonaws.com\/res_pro_thumb_images\/1174.jpg","address":{"area":"The St. Regis, Lower Parel","full_address":"The St. Regis, Senapati Bapat Marg, Lower Parel, Mumbai,The St. Regis, Lower Parel,mumbai,maharashtra,india,"},"menus":[],"restaurant_offers":[]},{"id":353,"name":"Lotus Cafe - JW Marriott Mumbai Juhu","description":"Sunday Brunches, Book a Table Online on Zomato","restaurant_type":null,"restaurant_url":null,"restaurant_facebook_url":null,"restaurant_google_url":null,"restaurant_zomato_url":"https:\/\/www.zomato.com\/mumbai\/lotus-cafe-jw-marriott-mumbai-juhu-juhu","average_ratings":"4.1","profile_image_file_name":"353.jpg","profile_image_content_type":"image\/jpeg","cover_image_file_name":null,"cover_image_content_type":null,"establishment_type":"Fine Dining","cost":"3500","cuisine":"Italian, Continental, North Indian, Asian","timing":"24 Hours","extras":null,"phone_numbers":[{"id":479,"restaurant_id":353,"number":"022 30151027","created_at":"2016-07-26T06:38:09.566-04:00","updated_at":"2016-07-26T06:38:09.566-04:00"}],"org_image_url":"http:\/\/comida-dev.s3.amazonaws.com\/res_pro_images\/353.jpg","thumb_image_url":"http:\/\/comida-dev.s3.amazonaws.com\/res_pro_thumb_images\/353.jpg","address":{"area":"JW Marriott Mumbai Juhu, Juhu","full_address":"JW Marriott, Juhu Tara Road, Juhu, Mumbai,JW Marriott Mumbai Juhu, Juhu,mumbai,maharashtra,india,"},"menus":[],"restaurant_offers":[{"id":235,"text":"\"A free pint of beer per person\"","offer_link":"https:\/\/www.eazydiner.com\/\/mumbai\/lotus-cafe-juhu-223153","resource":"eazydiner"}]},{"id":209,"name":"Aer - Four Seasons","description":"Romantic, Happy Hours, Rooftops, Summer Cocktails","restaurant_type":null,"restaurant_url":null,"restaurant_f
08-02 16:12:39.309 4782-4863/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa3d3b90
08-02 16:12:39.335 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@bc7b903
08-02 16:12:39.343 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
08-02 16:12:39.525 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@ed61575
08-02 16:12:39.526 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@9d457b
08-02 16:12:39.526 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@dff93f1
08-02 16:12:39.526 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@130be57
08-02 16:12:39.526 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@4687e2d
08-02 16:12:39.526 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@118e8f3
08-02 16:12:39.526 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@2fbd029
08-02 16:12:39.527 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@44f214f
08-02 16:12:39.567 4782-4792/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10269(920KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(288KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 1.626ms total 140.282ms
08-02 16:12:39.586 4782-4782/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Set Filpper Called: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie@45845e5
```

Comment: why are you taking listview inside viewflipper ? This is a wrong way of using viewflipper. You need to create imageview and add it to viewflipper. Check the details [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908862/how-to-set-dymanic-images-to-viewflipper-in-android)

Comment: where are you calling "setFlipperImage" method

Comment: Oh .Where i should call ?

Comment: This is the method which takes data from "movieList" arraylist. So once you set values to this array call this method. Call in the end of onResponse() after adding values to "movieList".

Comment: i have added and now i am getting only background image which i have set where image is not present it would be appear . But original images are not coming. i have edited again my changes .

Comment: Why are you using timer ? Do you want to show slide show with user interface or auto slide show ?

Comment: I want to do slide show with user interface but here according to code it should be  auto slide with timer but not happening.

Comment: If you want to show slide show without user involvement you can use viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true); . Remove your timer and add this line at the end of "setFlipperImage" method outside for loop.

Comment: i have made changes as per your suggestion now i am not getting background image . Only blank screen is appearing now . i have edit my changes

Comment: Put "setFlipperImage(movieList);" outside for loop. Also remove NetworkImageView in xml. You are creating the image programmatically in setFlipperImage() method.

Comment: i did still getting blank screen . i  have edited code and logcat .

Comment: did you remove networkimageView from xml and try?

Comment: After removing networkimageView from xml . only  background image is coming

Comment: Check whether your image URL is proper. You need to trace the code. This should work.

Comment: checked url is proper i am getting in list view but not getting in slider view